# Flash CS6 Importing sounds

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I'm working on a Flash project in CS6 and need to import a sound to my library but I'm having endless problems with it. I'm using external files in Actionscript 3.0 (e.g. I cannot do a URLRequest as it won't work externally, need to import)
I'm using a sound that should work, some errors go in that it can't be over 160kbps, this is only at 32 in the MP3 file. I converted it to an AIFF, no success, a WAV? no success. 
If it's an MP3 I simply get "Couldn't import "
If it's a AIFF or WAV I get "One or more files were not imported because there was a problem reading them"

Adobe suggest you need to files under 160kbps, all are set at 32kbps to be safe.
Another suggestion said you needed Quicktime 7.7.1 (or newer) and iTunes 10.5.5.3 (or newer) for this to work with an MP3 file. I have Quick 7.7.3 and iTunes 11.0 so I really have no idea of the problem.

Can anyone help, this project needs finished quickly.

Thanks.
John.

Answer (score 1):

Could be to do with bitrates.

I was running into issues with some mp3 files that I had converted from wav using Audacity. It was a specific few that wouldn't work, so I went back to Audacity and compared the working-mp3-yielding wavs to the non-working. I noticed that the working wavs had a bitrate of 44100Hz the non-working had 48000Hz. Setting the project rate ( bottom left corner ) to 44100Hz before exporting yielded mp3s that imported into flash with no problem.

In short:

- 48000 Hz = **naughty**
- 44100 Hz = **nice**

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird problem here's a simple code snippet that load and play an MP3 sound AS3 doesn't support WAV natively :

```
//sound object
var sound:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("music.mp3"))
var soundChannel:SoundChannel = sound.play();
```

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

This post is kind of old but I thought I would post an answer after running into the same problem.  I am also using Flash Pro in CS6.  What you want to do is to embed the sound into your FLA so that when your SWF is compiled the sound will go with it.  Khaled's answer is great but this issue needs a little more TLC.

What worked for me was to get an application that edits sound clips.  I downloaded the open source 'Audacity.'  In the bottom left corner of Audacity you can edit the project rate.  Take it down to about 1600 or lower.  Then save the project and export the sound as an mp3.

Finally, make sure that your sound clip is in the same folder as your FLA.  Import into your FLA (this should work now) and export your sound for actionscript by right clicking the sound in the library, going to properties.  Change the name of the class to whatever you want (at least get rid of the '.mp3' from the class name).

Then use the following code (which is different from the typical URL loader for sounds):

```
//sound is a constructor variable under your document class
public class DocumentClass extends MovieClip 
{
var yourSound:yourSoundClass;
public function DocumentClass()
{
init();
}
function init():void
{
yourSound = new yourSoundClass();
}
}
```

Then play your sound by using yourSound.play();  This technique will embed your sound within the SWF so it will go wherever the SWF goes.  I hope that helps anyone who runs into this.